# snapping anchors in CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a triangle and a line and i want the tip of the triangle to connect with the line. However, every single time illustrator wants to intersect with other shapes (there is quite a lot of stuff around it) and totally forgets to snap to the anchor at the end of the line. PLEASE help me before i throw my goddamned laptop out of the window.
How do i make illustrator prioritize snapping to anchors instead of snapping to stuff that is totally far away?

I have snap to pixel grid turned off btw

Comment: please add an image to make the problem more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turned out you have to physically grab the anchor in order to get it to snap to another anchor. This it totally counterintuitive for me, but at least i got my image. It would be great if you can just grab the shape anywhere and have an automatic snap to anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable features of smart guides. Go to **Edit → Preferences  → Smart Guides** and uncheck all the options. Smart guides will now snap to a considerably smaller set of things, and should snap more easily to endpoints.